# Exporting XML File from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a macro that does not run.

This macro is used to export an .xml file. When run this macro, a pop-up "Save as..file" appears. I press OK, an error occurs:

> "Runtime Error 9 : Subscript Out of Range"

I see error at line : `ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Root_Map").Export URL:=newFileName`

Thank you for helping.

```
Sub ExportXML()
'
' Export XML Macro exports the data that is in Excel to XML.
'
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO As Variant
Dim newFileName As Variant
Dim objFile As Variant
Dim strLine As Variant
Dim strNewContents As Variant
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'
newFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("out.xml", "XML Files (*.xml), *.xmls")
If newFileName = False Then
Exit Sub
End If
If objFSO.FileExists(newFileName) Then
objFSO.DeleteFile (newFileName)
End If
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Root_Map").Export URL:=newFileName


Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(newFileName, ForReading)


Dim count
count = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objFile.ReadLine
If count = 0 Then
strNewContents = strNewContents & "<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>" & vbCrLf
ElseIf count = 1 Then
strNewContents = strNewContents & "<Root xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/import.xsd"">" & vbCrLf
Else
strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
End If
count = count + 1

Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(newFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewContents

objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: That usually indicates that "Root_Map" does not exist. Have you verified it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Subscript out of range error means either variable newFileName or Root_Map is not defined correctly.

newFileName is defined. Test the xmlMaps.

```
Sub CheckXMLMaps()
Dim xmlMp As XmlMap
For Each xmlMp In ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps
    Debug.Print xmlMp.Name
Next xmlMp
End Sub
```

Check the names getting printed in immediate window.